# when my web updates iphone page, it zooms in a little, so user has to double tap to zoom out

Tags: ios, asp.net, objective-c, iphone, vb.net

How can the iphone4 automatic zoom-in behavior be disabled in a VB.NET app?

My VB.NET web app shows a page,
the user taps a button, 
and web updates page.

But on iPhone4 Safari, when user taps button, page zooms in a little.
User must double-tap display, and then it zooms out to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

I have limited development time, so I needed a solution that would work for ALL mobile browsers (I hope), so I just developed for the smallest (I assume) mobile still in (very) common use:  iPhone4, and assume it will work for Galaxy, iphone 5+  etc.